# ASP.NET MVC full offline website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, export, save, offline

I made an ASP.NET MVC application which allows user to create dynamic websites. I need to add feature which will allow to download from server off-line version of choosen website as static html files with menu, hyperlinks, images, documents etc. It should work similar to applications such as Teleport Pro, but I have to choose from Admin Panel which content should be export.

Client wants to burn static website on CD, save on pendrive.

Do you have any ideas how to begin? Please help.

Comment: it's probably never going to work if you need ASP.NET engine to process the websites you generate. ASP.NET requires .NET Framework, IIS and in most of the cases a database. Unless the websites you download only have static html and javascript files and css. All the server side code needs to be processed by IIS or a similar / compatible web server.

Comment: Yes it's clear, but is it possible to: loop through all positions in menu, generate a view, save static file on some folder on server, save content(images/documents) on some folder on server, modify links on fly etc? Should I do in such way or search other idea?

Answer (score 2):

I currently have implemented that in a [current project](http://admin.julekal.info)...

User is able to change anything in the frontend and at the end he can publish and download the offline files... the site subscribe users and show all prizes, winners and more information about that campaign.

All was done in **ASP.NET MVC3** under **.NET4** and hosted in [**AppHarbor**](http://appharbor.com).

It's composed at several applications but for what you want, you develop the Backend and the Frontend, and to generate the static files, simple use the Frontend to grab the full HTML

As an example, I can show what 2 users did...

**Callme.dk** did http://callme.julekal.info and
**Sony Nordic** did http://sony.julekal.info

plus, you can simply point custom domains to it as well like http://sonynordicxmas.net/

*To publish and generate all files:*

[image]

*one part of the editing:*

[image]

So I give the users, offline access (through the `.zip` file), online access (through the frontend application) and the ability of using custom domains...

Comment: Sounds great. I have to do this as simple as possible. I need to give publish button on page and save all sites as static files on some server folder. Could you give me some suggestions to start?

Comment: I never save on the server, I use Amazon S3 to host any file that is uploaded by the user so I can show it in dynamic website and avoid having my application serving static files witch just cost bandwidth and cpu for nothing... So, all files are handled externaly using  [Amazon SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/). You can see the source code to see where the images are being pulled from.

Comment: I have to create total offline website copy. It should work without Internet access. I have to save html files, copy images, documents, remove routes, change all hyperlinks and so on.

Comment: no problem, in your application, your Views will point to pre-designated routes, so they can work offline, for example `@Url.Action("click here", "Index", "Stats")` and you're route is `{controller}/{action}.html?{id}`

Comment: How did you make offline copy of your websites? I'm going to:
1. Read all menu positions,
2. Loop for all menu positions with WebClient,
3. Use DownloadString Method of WebClient Class,
4. Save all of page as separate html file.

I think how to copy only necessary uploaded files (images, documents).

Good direction?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way this might be possible is if you go to every single page and then use your browser to "Save" the web page script and all.

However this causes several issues;

1. You never quite get everything and you need to massage the HTML produced, dowload all the images etc to get the page to look right
2. Each html file now has an associated folder with the same name and each time you do this you will get another html file with a folder.  You can combine all the folders into a single one but that leads me to item 3.
3. You will need to edit each html file to clear up any pathing issues if you want to share a single source folder.
4. Data is no longer dynamic!
5. You need to, if you want to link all the pages to each other, edit every single html file and resolver the anchor tags.

This is too much work and I think it actually breaks the true requirement.

Don't do it! :)